# Having trouble setting Rolename and RoleInstance with OpenTelemetry using Python

Tags: python-3.x, open-telemetry

I am trying to setup `OpenTelemetry` logging with Python. I need to update the RoleName and RoleInstance but unable to set it as mentioned in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-configuration?tabs=python#set-the-cloud-role-name-and-the-cloud-role-instance).

Tried adding:

```
os.environ["OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES"] = "service.namespace=my-namespace,service.instance.id=my-instance"
os.environ["OTEL_SERVICE_NAME"] = "my-service"
```

Tried setting span attributes which adds the attributes to custom parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to replicate your issue. The cloud role name and instance are successfully set using the code below:

```
import os

import requests
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
from opentelemetry import trace

os.environ["OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES"] = "service.namespace=my-namespace,service.instance.id=my-instance"
os.environ["OTEL_SERVICE_NAME"] = "my-service"


# Configure Azure monitor collection telemetry pipeline
configure_azure_monitor()

tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
with tracer.start_as_current_span("Request parent span") as span:
    response = requests.get("https://azure.microsoft.com/", timeout=5)
    response = requests.get("http://example.com", timeout=5)

input()
```

Go to `Application Map` blade in Application Insights portal to see your application with custom cloud role name:

[image]

As an fyi, if you would like your issues related to Azure monitor Opentelemetry to be responded quicker, I would create an issue in the [gitHub repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=bug_report.md&title=) which is more actively monitored.